# Proving $E =pc$ by simple algebraic relationship is right?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

If we use deBroglie's wavelength of wave function relationship: 
$\lambda =h/p$, where $p$ is the momentum of a particle
And 
$E = hc/\lambda$

Obtain the relationship $$hc/ E = h/p$$
Simplifying the relationship, we get 
$$E= pc $$
Which is basically, 
$$E^2 = m^2\cdot c^4 + (p\cdot c)^2$$
but with $m=0$.

Is this a legitimate way to obtain this relationship? Because it doesn't seem right since the wavefunction is not directly related to the wavelength right?
I'm 15 and have had no proper course in QM so please excuse me for my incompetence.

Comment: only particles with zero mass move with velocity c. have a look here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality#De_Broglie.27s_wavelength

Comment: "the wavefunction is not directly related to the wavelength": what do you mean? You haven't used any wavefunction, have you?

Comment: Note that you can also obtain this relationship for the energy- and momentum-density ofclassical electromagnetic waves, which is a nice correspondence between various ways of thinking about light.

Comment: @annav I know that but if they have 0 mass how is their momentum specified? Is it equal to h/lambda ?

Comment: with c=1 units energy and momentum are equal for zero mass particles . see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass#As_defined_in_particle_physics

Comment: @anna: The question comes from a 15 years old. Do you really think a nonstandard unit system is enlightening?

Comment: @user167920: You should be more specific. You are asking "Is this a legitimate way to obtain **this** relationship?" For me it's not clear to which equation you are referring. The derivation if fine for  $E= pc$, but it's _not_ for $E=\sqrt{(mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2}$.

Comment: @Semoi that is why I gave the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algebra that you have done seems legit, as long as you are aware of your conclusions' limitations. De Broglie's relation and $E=hc/\lambda$ only hold exactly for free massless particles. They are very good approximations for massive particles as long as $mc \ll p$. The equation $E=pc$ is exactly correct for photons, and it is frequently used for light particles such as electrons produced in high-energy collisions.

I will comment that there are a lot of equations floating around in the literature, and it is good that you are drawing connections between them like this, but I take issue with your choice of the word "prove" in the question's title. Theorists have put an awful lot of effort into carefully deriving these equations from some very basic assumptions, and it pays to keep track of the whole infrastructure behind your proof's assumptions. For example, de Broglie originally came up with his relationship phenomenologically, but nowadays we can derive it from Schroedinger's equation. You get $E=hc/\lambda$ after incorporating either special relativity or Maxwell's equations, either of which can directly give you $E=pc$.

Also, as @Luc J. Bourhis has noted, it is not clear why you use the word "wavefunction" in your question, so maybe this answer does not address the source of your confusion?

Comment: I have recently read that the reason why macro objects like us don't exhibit wave like nature is the inverse proportionality between lambda and p. I am confused as to what kind of waves are they talking about. I read it in an android app called quantum. If it's implying that matter also behaves like electromagnetic waves that would that have to do with anything with uncertainty in it's position?

Comment: @user167920  The wave nature of elementary particles ,  are probability density waves, i.e. the probability of finding a particle at  (x, y,z) at time t has a sinusoidal behavior, showing interference patterns . All quantum mechanical solutions are from differential equations which have sinusoidal solutions and that is why they are called wave functions. The complex conjugate square of these wavefunctions describe mathematically  the probability density.  The de Broglie guess is described by this.